# Python - Can't implement Scipy fitting script

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to implement the Scipy script from section "Simplifying the syntax" here: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FittingData.html

My code is quite long, so I'll post only the parts that seem to be the problem.

I get the following error message: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Parameter'`, which I understand why it happens: it's the product in this part: `return self.amplitude() * np.exp(-1*self.decay_const()*x)`

```
class Plot():

    def __init__(self,slice_and_echo,first_plot,right_frame):

        self.slice_and_echo = slice_and_echo
        self.first_plot     = first_plot
        self.right_frame    = right_frame

        self.amplitude = Parameter(1)
        self.decay_const = Parameter(1)

    def function(self,x):
        print(self.amplitude)
        print(self.amplitude())
        return self.amplitude() * np.exp(-1*self.decay_const()*x)

    def create_plot(self):
        plot_figure = Figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=100)
        self.the_plot = plot_figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.the_plot.plot(self.echoes,self.average,'ro')

        print(self.amplitude())

        self.fit_parameters = self.fit(self.function,[self.amplitude,self.decay_const],self.average)
        print(self.fit_parameters)


    def fit(self,function, parameters, y, x=None):

        def f(params):
            i = 0
            for p in parameters:
                p.set(params[i])
                i += 1
            return y - function(x)

        if x is None: x = np.arange(y.shape[0])

        p = [param for param in parameters]

        return optimize.leastsq(f, p)
```

and the Parameter()  class is the same as in the link:

```
class Parameter:
    def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value

    def set(self, value):
            self.value = value

    def __call__(self):
            return self.value
```

The issue seems to be that, when I call `self.amplitude()` inside of the `create_plot(self):` method, the value it returns is an integer (which is what I want!). But that doesn't happen when I call it inside of the `function(self,x)` method; when I print it inside this method I get: `<__main__.Parameter object at 0x1162845c0>` instead of the integer 1.

Why would it return different values when called from different methods in the same class? What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a typo in list comprehension. Your code states:

```
p = [param for param in parameters]
```

and the example code states:

```
p = [param() for param in parameters]
```

Note that in your case you are generating a list of objects of type `Parameter` instead of a list of numbers.

By the way, check out module called **lmfit** - it simplifies fitting routines by great deal.

Comment: Could not help but notice familiar equations. I was working with photon echo decay curves a while ago, so some of this code may be helpful: fit decay curve: https://github.com/9dogs/edp/blob/1b9d6629922db404ed397e150f9d1482be0b376e/main.py#L474 fit peak curve: https://github.com/9dogs/edp/blob/1b9d6629922db404ed397e150f9d1482be0b376e/fitting/fit.py#L41

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried a lot of things to implement it and probably forgot to put the parenthesis back at some point.

And thanks for the code! I'll take a look at it!

Comment: I managed to implement lmfit! Thanks! One question, though: do we need to extract the parameters and create the fitting curve ourselves? Or can we extract the curve from the minimize method output?

Comment: ModelResult object returned from `model.fit()` method got all that you need in its [methods](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#modelresult-methods) and [attributes](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#modelresult-attributes): `eval`, `best_fit`, `params`...